# WSO2 CEP bucket creation error

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, wso2-cep

I was trying to execute the sample Access Analysis from the WSO CEP samples. After I created the bucket same as given in the sample I received an error and it doesn't created the bucket. Can any one help what is the problem?

Error log:

```
[2012-12-13 15:09:21,654]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine} -
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: wrong configuration provided for adding AccessAnalysisBucket.xml
```

This error was appearing when I gave query syntax at the Add query Expression. If i am not giving this, it will create the bucket.